# How do I log wordpress users without password

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to login wordpress users without password. This is what I want. 
Say user visits `http://example-site.com/6789098765678.php` and on the page he'll enter his username, he'll be automatically logged in without password.

I've tried some things like `wp_set_auth_cookie` and all but I don't know where to put. I come from a Ruby on Rails background and have very minimal knowledge about PHP.

I know that this behavior is not secure. It's a specific use case.

Comment: By default wordpress does not provide any kind of functionality you are looking for. The best way to make this possible , should be creating your own plugin and connect the plugin to users table and then create your custom login forms with username only. save the original password of users into usermeta (not the salted and hashed one) , and then when user enter it's username to login. fetch the password from usermeta based on username and then submit that password and username to wordpress login function , which will login the user and set the session.

Comment: @ArshSingh Then how's this possible? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53503/can-i-programmatically-login-a-user-without-a-password

Comment: if you want to use that - did you check this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/128445/66430

Comment: Just curious, given anyone can log in as anyone, what is the value of a username?

Comment: @DamienSugden I have a backend solution for authenticating users. Instead of password, I want to use it.

Comment: @ArshSingh, That's where I've a doubt. Where to post that code? Sorry about this. But I'm really unaware of wordpress work flow. Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @NinjaBoy check my answer below , to know how you need to use that code. i have create whole tutorial for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer that i have posted inside the comments , you can use that in the following way.

What you need to make this possible is. Create `ajax hooks` for wordpress function which we are going to use for user login only with username, and , jQuery ajax call to that function.

First step to do here is go to : `wp-content/themes/your_theme_name/` And open the file named `functions.php` , then at the end of the file add the following code.

```
function username_login(){
// Automatic login //
$username = $_POST['username'];
$user = get_user_by('login', $username );



 // Redirect URL //
    if ( !is_wp_error( $user ) )
    {
        wp_clear_auth_cookie();
        wp_set_current_user ( $user->ID );
        wp_set_auth_cookie  ( $user->ID );

        $redirect_to = user_admin_url();
        echo json_encode(array('error_code'=>0));
        exit();
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('error_code'=>1));
        exit();
    }
 exit();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_username_login','username_login');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_username_login','username_login');
```

As you can see , we have used a `add_action` function to hook to our `username_login` function from the ajax controller , read more about [wordpress hooks here](https://developer.wordpress.org/?s=&post_type%5B%5D=wp-parser-hook)

The next step we need here is to make a ajax call to the function that we have created and make user login and then refresh the site when user is logged in. What you need is use the following code to send the request to Wordpress for login the user. Add the below code to your footer.php file, which is located inside `wp-content/themes/your_theme_name/` and open `footer.php` :

```
jQuery('#username_login').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serializeArray();
    data.push({ name:'action',value:'username_login' });
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:data,
        success:function(response){
            if(response.error_code == 1){
                alert('user cannot login')
            } else {
                alert('user logged in');
                location.reload();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see in the above javascript code , we have form selector called `username_login` , what we need to do now is create a form element with the id `username_login` and inside it we need to create a input called `username` with button type `submit` :

```
<form id="username_login">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Your username..." required/>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Now that you have all , how this is going to work with this flow? . Well , when the user enters the username and hits the Login , an ajax request will be sent to the url : `yoursite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=username_login` , with the parameter called `action` and when the user logs in the site will be refreshed as the user is logged in and then user will  have access to the normal user's features without any problem.

Comment: Thanks for the time you've taken to answer my question. While this is one approach, An easy approach is Just pasting the code here : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53503/can-i-programmatically-login-a-user-without-a-password/128445#128445 in some PHP file and adding the line `require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );` to the file in the starting. it's a simple workaround :D

Comment: Upvoting and accepting as this is one way that does the job. But I've used the workaround which I've specified earlier.

Comment: Your workaround is also good , the one that i have posted , it is for incase you need to create something more dynamic and based on javascript. You can make in that way.